# Creating a self signed cert. to be used on an externally hosted site

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

Is it possible to generate a self signed certificate for use on a site which is hosted externally?  The only users for this are ourselves and this particular site is IP restricted to our given IP range.

While I realise this is completely possible when hosting a site internally i.e. intranet but would this work externally and/or what would need to be done to enable us to do this?

On Windows/IIS setup

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will it work?  Yes, absolutely; you'll just have your users clicking through warnings each time they visit the site.

That's not something you want your users to be used to doing, so if it's feasible I'd recommend setting up an internal certificate authority, and having your domain computers trust that CA - much better than just using self-signed certs and numbing your users out of paying attention to cert warnings.

Comment: +1 -- If you don't want to fork over the cash for an externally signed (& trusted) cert you need to set up your own CA. It's more work initially, but it will provide great value long-term and avoid numbing your users to warnings they should really pay attention to.

Comment: Thanks Shane, I'm under the impression we already have an internal CA for use with Exchange so i'll investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a windows hosted server or linux?

I don't see this being a problem, but you will find that the browser will throw a fit. Either way take a read at [This](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html) if you plan on using an apache/linux setup.